# localhost connection database

Tags: localhost, ping

I can't seem to connect to localhost on my local machine. I go into the terminal and type:

```
ping google.com
```

And I see the IP address.

If I then go to try to ping my localhost,

```
ping 127.0.0.1
```

I see nothing.

Where does my local router connect to?

## edit

ipconfig:

```
rick@instance-2:~$ ipconfig
No command 'ipconfig' found, did you mean:
 Command 'tpconfig' from package 'tpconfig' (universe)
 Command 'ifconfig' from package 'net-tools' (main)
 Command 'iwconfig' from package 'wireless-tools' (main)
ipconfig: command not found
```

## edit2

ifconfig:

```
rick@instance-2:~$ ifconfig

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:31709438 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:31709438 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:22644332327 (22.6 GB)  TX bytes:22644332327 (22.6 GB)

lo:0      Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:192.168.0.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
```

Comment: I've edited my question now

Comment: ifconfig results are in

Answer (score 0):

You can disconnect from your remote host on your local human by going out of the terminal and mashing:

```
tracert google.com
```

There you will unsee the PI address

```
tracert 127.0.0.1
```

You see EVERYTHING

That is where your remote funnel disconnects from